# LSTM keras MaxMinScale function producing different values for the same number

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to apply LSTM model to do timeseries forecasting.

One step in LSTM is to scale the data using MinMaxScaler. I'm trying to scale the data in the range (-1,1).

My train data looks something like below:

```
[[0.         2.54583333]
 [2.54583333 2.6125    ]
 [2.6125     2.875     ]
 ...
 [2.69583333 2.5125    ]
 [2.5125     2.91666667]
 [2.91666667 3.4375    ]]

MinMaxScaler(copy=True, feature_range=(-1, 1))
[[-1.         -0.95342466]
 [-0.80649248 -0.94794521]
 [-0.80142518 -0.92636986]
 ...
 [-0.79509105 -0.95616438]
 [-0.80902613 -0.92294521]
 [-0.77830562 -0.88013699]]
```

As, it can be seen above the values are not getting scaled properly. For eg: 2.54583333 is getting scaled to -0.95342466 as well as -0.80649248.

Actually the scaled values should look something like below:

```
[[-1.         -0.95342466]
 [-0.95342466 -0.94794521]
 [0.94794521 -0.92636986]
 ...
 [-0.79509105 -0.95616438]
 [-0.95616438 -0.92294521]
 [-0.92294521 -0.88013699]]
```

Scaled values should also follow the pattern in the training set.

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong, why multiple scaled values are coming for the same number?

I'm scaling values using below code:

```
def scale(train, test):
    # fit scaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scaler = scaler.fit(train)

    # transform train
    train = train.reshape(train.shape[0], train.shape[1])
    train_scaled = scaler.transform(train)

    # transform test
    test = test.reshape(test.shape[0], test.shape[1])
    test_scaled = scaler.transform(test)
    return scaler, train_scaled, test_scaled
```

But something is really wrong here. Please help.

My whole dataset is of shape (720,1)

Length of train data : 519
Length of test data : 200.

In the above method the shape of train data is (519,2) and test data is (200,2). Please let me know if more information or any other clarity required. I am new to this and I'm trying LSTM for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with this. Each feature is scaled independently, and each has its own normalization factors, so the same feature value in a different feature dimension will not be normalized in the same way.